# order rows by highest value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database that has a list of company names and there score values.

I want to order the rows by the highest sum of the urls which are identical.

I'm not sure how to explain this correctly.

I though this MySQL query would work `select * from table order by url asc, total desc` but that does not display the sum of the identical urls at the top.

```
url        total
=======    =======
ASOS        222
Tesco       11
ASOS        11111
Tesco       123
ASOS        22
Argos       12345
Argos       2
```

The query should display the rows in this order

```
url        total
=======    =======
Argos       12345
Argos       2
ASOS        11111
ASOS        222
ASOS        22
Tesco       123
Tesco       11
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can aggregate in a subquery then `JOIN` to use the grand total in your `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT a.url,a.total
FROM YourTable a
JOIN (SELECT url,SUM(total) as gTotal
      FROM YourTable
      GROUP BY url) b
  ON a.url = b.url
ORDER BY b.gTotal DESC,a.total DESC
```

Edit:  Might add `url` before `a.total` in your `ORDER BY` in case there's a tie on grand total between two values of url, just depends on your preferred behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I create a table and enter the same data than you and it worked fine for me.

Are you sure total is an integer and not a string ?

Just go on your databases tape this and paste the result here please.

> desc your_table